# Is there any way in Java to log *every* Thread interrupt?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, interrupt

I would like to somehow log every time `Thread.interrupt()` is called, logging which Thread issued the call (and its current stack) as well as identifying information about which Thread is being interrupted.

Is there a way to do this?  Searching for information, I saw someone reference the possibility of implementing a security manager.  Is this something that can be done at runtime (e.g., in an Applet or Web Start client), or do you need to tool the installed JVM to do this?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I can think of a few ways of doing it with different complexity and different performance hits. Is it a one-time thing to find a bug or is it something you want in production?

Comment: This is primarily something I want as a one-time thing, but something that I know I will want to use from time to time.  If it was friendly enough, I would leave it in production code but disabled as an additional mode of remote debugging (via logs) to be used when needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a quick hack, this was a *lot* easier to do than I thought it would be.  Since this is a quick hack, I didn't do things like ensure that the stack trace is deep enough before dereferencing the array, etc.  I inserted the following in my signed Applet's constructor:

```
log.info("Old security manager = " + System.getSecurityManager());
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
      @Override
      public void checkAccess(final Thread t) {
        StackTraceElement[] list = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement element = list[3];
        if (element.getMethodName().equals("interrupt")) {
          log.info("CheckAccess to interrupt(Thread = " + t.getName() + ") - "
                   + element.getMethodName());
          dumpThreadStack(Thread.currentThread());
        }
        super.checkAccess(t);
      }
    });
```

and the `dumpThreadStack` method is as follows:

```
public static void dumpThreadStack(final Thread thread) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder('\n');
  try {
    for (StackTraceElement element : thread.getStackTrace()) {
      builder.append(element.toString()).append('\n');
    }
  } catch (SecurityException e) { /* ignore */ }
  log.info(builder.toString());
}
```

I could never, of course, leave this in production code, but it sufficed to tell me exactly which thread was causing an `interrupt()` that I didn't expect.  That is, with this code in place, I get a stack dump for every call to `Thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: Note that in some versions of java the SecurityManager should also override the checkPermission methods (for the most permissive and simplest option, have them simply return) or else you may hit security errors like `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied`.

Answer (score 4):

Before trying anything too wild, have you considered using the [Java debugging](http://docs.rinet.ru/JaTricks/ch26.htm) [API](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html)?  I'd think that capturing MethodEntryEvents on Thread.interrupt() would do it.

Eeek, that's the old interface, you should also check oout the new [JVM Tool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html) [Interface](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/enhancements.html).

Comment: I am vaguely aware of the Java debugging API, but I'm not sure how to use it from within the application that I would use it upon.

Comment: I've given you a couple of links now; the short answer is that you add a flag to the JVM invocation, and then can connect to the JVM externally.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestions won't help me.  The new JVM Tool Interface requires JNI and the old Java debugging API is not available to Applets.  However, this information may prove useful for something else in the future.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You should be able to get at JDPA in an applet; you need to get at the plugin control stuff.  See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html#Plugin

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and its capabilities to wrap method calls. An [execution pointcut](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html#some-example-pointcuts) around the `interrupt()` method should help here.

Note that since you're looking to intercept a Java system method call (as opposed to your application code), the above *may* not be suitable. [This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg07750.html) seems to suggest it's possible, but note that he's created a *woven* rt.jar.

Comment: You can even wrap methods in the JVM libraries?

Comment: That's a good point, and one I was considering just as I typed it. There are various different byte-weaving mechanisms, certainly (compile-time/run-time/class-load time) so one of these may work.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said... If it is a one-time thing JVMTI is probably the most hardcore way to go. However, just as fun could be to use the asm library and the instrumentation APIs to create an agent that inserts a call to a static method you've created just before the Thread.interrupt() call (or maybe alters the Thread.interrupt() method to do the same, I think you can do that).

Both takes some time to learn but it is quite fun to work with and once you get the hold of it you can use them for all kinds of funny things in the future :-)
I don't really have any good snippets to paste here right now but if you google around for ASM and maybe look at the JIP for some creative use of ASM I think you will find inspiration.

JIP: [Java Interactive Profiler](http://jiprof.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I assume you're referring to http://asm.ow2.org/  ?  Sounds very creative!  I didn't have the time to investigate, but this looks like something that'll do me good in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: Correct, sorry for not including the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try also with JMX:

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadInfo(aThreadID)
```

with the [ThreadInfo](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html) object you can log:

- the stack trace of the thread
- general userful information like name, status, etc
- etc

**EDIT**

use getAllThreadIds() in order to obtain the list of live thread ids:

```
long[] ids = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getAllThreadIds();
```

Comment: How do you mean that would catch the interrupt-call?

Comment: using another method (JVM instrumentation, debugging hooks, AOP, etc)?