# Is there a way for a thread to tell which thread has interrupted it?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

Is there a way for a thread to tell which thread has interrupted it?

Eg.:

```
...
if (isInterrupted())  {
    // look-up the thread that interrupted this
        // act accordingly
}
```

[Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) isn't showing anything.

//========================

EDIT:

It isn't a message or event mechanism i'm looking for.

but, this as is seems very raw. 
a way to get the class type, thread group or maybe just the priority of the interrupting 
thread would carry some info to work on.

typical use is system shut-down-- interrupting them all to get them out of their 
blocking methods, and there isn't another i can think of now.

Comment: I feel like interrupts aren't the right notification mechanism. Can you describe your use case?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way for a thread to tell which thread has interrupted it?

In a word: No.

There is no functionality in that standard Java SE class libraries that support this.

Indeed, even the problem is not well defined:

- What happens if a thread is interrupted multiple times by different threads?  Which one should be reported?
- What about race conditions between a thread detecting that it has been interrupted (e.g. via a `isInterrupted` call) and finding out what thread did it?

As Sotirios commented: if the signalled thread needs to find out which thread signalled it, then `interrupt` is probably the wrong mechanism.  You probably to build your own event mechanism in which the events *carry* the information you need with them.

Comment: Yeah. Event mechanisms sounds much better.

Answer (score 2):

Before you interrupt the thread, store the needed information somewhere the interrupted thread can get it. Then when the thread is interrupted, have it check for that information wherever you stored it.

Comment: Assuming a multithreaded (more than 2) environment, how do you guarantee the interrupted thread sees the info of the thread that interrupted it?

Comment: You finish storing the info before you interrupt the thread, protecting the container that holds the info with appropriate synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell in a standard Thread and as mentioned if you need this, then a Queue is more likely to be useful.

In this case, a better solution is likely to be a state change.

e.g.

```
// change state in a thread safe manner
sharedObject.setState(Mode.ACTION);
thread.interrupt();


// doesn't need to know about other threads, just state changes.
if (isInterrupted())  {
    switch(sharedObject.getState()) {
        case ACTION:

    }
}
```

More generically, you could inject tasks for the thread to run.

```
 // calling thread needs an action to perform.
 sharedThread.execute(runnable); // or invokeLater()

 // polling thread, use take() if you want to block.
 for(Runnable run; (run = runQueue.poll()) != null;)
      run.run();
```

However, this doesn't mean it can't be done just because it's probably not a good idea.

```
public class Main {

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        protected final Queue<Thread> interruptingThreads = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        MyThread(Runnable target) {
            super(target);
        }

        public Queue<Thread> getInterruptingThreads() {
            return interruptingThreads;
        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            interruptingThreads.add(Thread.currentThread());
            super.interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) throws Exception {
        Thread t = new MyThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println("Interrupted by :" + ((MyThread) Thread.currentThread()).getInterruptingThreads());
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

prints

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Interrupted by :[Thread[main,5,]]
```

If this is debugging purposes, you could also add a stack trace of where the interrupting thread, called `interrupt()`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the interrupting thread for debugging, not actually in the code, I found the following post to be helpful, which describes adding a new SecurityManager: [Is there any way in Java to log *every* Thread interrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799023/is-there-any-way-in-java-to-log-every-thread-interrupt#799647)